# How do I present a ViewController from a button click in webView? Swift/Xcode

Tags: swift, webview, io

Here is my Swift

```
     func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.formSubmitted) {
        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UITabBarController") as? UITabBarController

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC!)
        self.navigationController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion:nil)


    }
    return true
}
```

And here is my HTML file that is loaded in webView

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
presentViewController('UITabBarController');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="myFunction" type="submit" onClick="myFunction"     value="myFunction">
</body>
</html>
```

This just not working, any advise?
I don't mind if it's a link instead of a button also.

It's  webView inside  viewcontroller, after clicking the Link/button, it will present a next viewcontroller which has tabbar.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try by opening a link? You should receive a *func webView(UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType)* delegate callback. Here you should check if the link is the one triggering the view controller opening. If it is the special link you will open the viewController and return false. else return true.